# Match Data is acting weird

Tags: ios, game-center

My app has this code to handle matchData sending (Talking about GKTurnBasedMatch)-

```
GKTurnBasedMatch *currentMatch = [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] currentMatch];
    NSString *newStoryString;
    if ([textInputField.text length] >= 250) {
        newStoryString = [textInputField.text substringToIndex:249];
    }
    else if ([textInputField.text length] <= 19) {
        characterCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d to send", 20 - [textInputField.text length]];
        [characterCountLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:17]];
        characterCountLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return;
    }
    else if ([textInputField.text length] <250 && [textInputField.text length] >= 20) {
        newStoryString = textInputField.text;
    }
    NSLog(@"New %@", newStoryString);

        if ([newStoryString length] >0){
            NSLog(@"Main %@", mainTextController.text);
            NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", mainTextController.text, newStoryString];
            NSLog(@"Send %@", sendString);

        NSData *data = [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
        mainTextController.text = sendString;
            NSLog(@"Send %@", sendString);
```

The mainTextController is a UITextView that is responsible for displaying the matchData at the end of the match.
Now, the weird behaviour- say I'm sending hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

First log is- new hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Second is- Main hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii (notice the sudden multiplication)

Third is- send hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii (well, that's because it's sending what was there and the new text).

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is sending a text, which is combined with what was already sent (nothing or something), and then display it in the mainTextController. This should go to all of the players.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your mainController.text contains the hi text twice and you're adding a third one to it. So for me it looks like it does what you want. If you tested it before it's normal behaviour that it remembers the text, because a match is persistent on Apple's servers.

Comment: I managed to solve it- called a few times to my method of sending match data.